# WebStorm how to turn on ASCII symbol?

Tags: webstorm

[image]

WebStorm does not show ASCII symbol. How to display it?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at the moment.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-115572 -- watch this and related tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

**P.S.**
For certain dangerous/breaking symbols you could use **"Zero Width Characters locator" plugin** -- it warns user when it sees such symbols/sequences in your code that potentially can break it.